# How to analyze abrupt session restarts?

Tags: restart, data-loss

Sometimes, my Ubuntu session abruptly restarts without a warning. Sometimes my documents are lost (for example, once my Libre Office Writer document gets lost).

How can I analyze the issue?

Comment: Immediately after your session crashes (most easily in a terminal opened after switching to a text console via Ctrl-Alt-F1) type `ls -rlt /var/log` to see the most recently modified log file or three. Look at the end of these for hints.